# Object-oriented paradigms (SOLID) violated in Python? (example: subclassing of tuple to implement FractionTuple)

Tags: python, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I was quite surprised to see that Python - at least partially - seems to violate some oo / [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles.

Example:

```
class FractionTuple(tuple):
def __new__(cls, p, q):
    # Ensure that p and q are integers
    if not isinstance(p, int) or not isinstance(q, int):
        raise TypeError("Both elements must be integers")
    # Create the tuple of length 2
    return super().__new__(cls, (p, q))
```

From a code reuse perspective this seems like a practical way to go - however it violates the substitutability principle: preconditions to use the derived class `FractionTuple` are strengthened compared to the base class `tuple`.

The [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (LSP) is a criterion in object-oriented programming on conditions for modeling a subclass. It states that a program that uses objects of a base class must also work correctly with objects of the derived subclass without changing the program. In terms of individual methods this means that when a method is overwritten by a derived class, the preconditions may only be weakened and the postconditions may only be strengthened. A common example that violates LSP is a base class `ellipse` and a derived class `circle`.

Is this violation common practice in the Python community, i.e. is code re-use preferred oder LSP? Or is the FractionTuple an exception?

Comment: Constructors are an exemption! *Instances* must be compatible, not constructors. When `Circle` inherits from `Shape`, its constructor also looks very different and is custom specific to the requirements of `Circle`.

Comment: The literature says: “If S is a declared subtype of T, objects of type S should behave as objects of type T are expected to behave, if they are treated as objects of type T”. I see no distinction between constructors and other methods. There are of course other conflicts with this subclassing: the '+' operator acting on tupels concats them, which is no longer reasonable with fractions.

Answer (score 1):

As you quote:

> “If S is a declared subtype of T, objects of type S should behave as objects of type T are expected to behave, if they are treated as objects of type T”

The important point here is: ***objects of** type*. In other words, once you have an instance, that instance must behave in a way compatible with objects of its super type. **How you get such an instance** is a different story.

So, *this* must work:

```
def foo(bar: T):
    bar.baz()
```

This function expects *an instance* of type `T`. You may also pass it an instance of type `S`, as long as it correctly implements `baz`. *This* is what the LSP is about.

The LSP says nothing about *constructing* an instance from a type. *Of course* this instantiation will widely differ between different types. If all types would also be required to implement the exact same constructor, there would be very little room to let them implement any customisation whatsoever. Example:

```
class Shape(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def area(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return math.pi * (self.radius ** 2)


class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def area(self):
        return self.length ** 2
```

The instance method `area` must be compatible, but of course a `Circle` needs different constructor arguments than a `Square` needs different constructor arguments than a `Polygon`.

In more practical terms, if you're implementing a, say, session storage backend, you may implement several alternative classes, like a database-backed storage, an in-memory storage and a file-backed storage. These objects can all present the same *instance interface* to store and retrieve session information, but of course will take very different constructor arguments. The database-backed store takes a database connection, the in-memory store probably takes nothing, and the file-store takes a path to a local directory.

Comment: The problem is not only the constructor, there are other problems as well: The operator '+' will concat tuples (2, 7) + (-1, 3) = (2, 7, -1, 3) but add fractions (2, 7) + (-1, 3) = ( -1, 21). This violates LSP. So the problem is not just the constructor, but the entire idea to implement a fraction class based on subclassing.

Comment: The result is still one tuple plus another tuple results in a tuple. That a subclass changes the *specific* behaviour is part of the point of subclasses.

Comment: Do you know what behavioral subtyping means? Suppose there is a class deque from which we derive the subclass stack. put() and pop() act on different ends of the deque but on the same end of the stack, therefore this subclassing is in conflict with behavioral subtyping: the behavior of deque and stack w.r.t. push() and pop() is different. I hope you agree that a stack is not a subclass of deque. The same applies for to tuples and fractions. For tuples t1 = (a, b), t2 = (c, d) the expectation is t1 + t2 = ((a, b), (c, d)) which contradicts the expected behavor for addition of fractions.

Comment: 1) It depends on how you define the behaviour that you're expecting. In terms of *types*, only the call signatures and return types need to be compatible, *not the behaviour*. Whether something `pop`s from the front or back is its specific behaviour; as far as the LSP is concerned `pop()` just needs to be callable without argument and the object must be modified *in place*. Same for tuple addition, as long as two tuples *can* be added together and result in another tuple, the *type system* isn't violated.

Comment: 2) What even is `FractionTuple`? It's not a core Python class, so accusing Python of violating something is weird. Assuming that `FractionTuple` did violate something, it wouldn't be *Python* doing it. It'd be some author somewhere. That Python *lets you do it* is fine; Python lets you shoot your own foot in many ways if you so choose, as does any programming language. 3) This is now a discussion going afield. Your original question was about a specific example showing a constructor, and I've clearly answered that. Continuing this with something else is a different topic.

Comment: I was always talking about the behavior as essential part of LSP. My question was "Is this violation common practice in Python?"

Comment: That's a subjective question. Both whether "it's common", but also whether anything is being violated when adding `FractionTuple`s. What *are* the pre- and postconditions of adding tuples? Is it specified that the resulting tuple must fulfil `len(a) + len(b) = len(c)`? Python only vaguely defines `s + t — the concatenation of s and t` for "common sequence types". Does `FractionTuple`'s implementation violate this vaguely defined "postcondition"?

Comment: Behavioral subtyping means that subclasses should satisfy the expectations of clients accessing subclass objects through references of superclass type, _not_ just as re _syntactic safety_ but also as re _behavioral correctness_ (the example of dequeue and stack). If I have a couple of objects derived from tuple where some overwrite __add__() to implement addition of fractions. Here the principle of least astonishment is violated. I don't blame Python itself to violate these principles, therefore I corrected my question the in first post.

Comment: Again, some author implementing some `class FractionTuple` somewhere which might arguably violate some expectation or another is hardly a basis to make any general statements. I'd guess "the Python community" as such is as fond of the LSP as the next community, but that's neither here nor there.